# C++ strftime %b not working as expected

Tags: c++, datetime, locale, strftime

I want to print timestamp using C++ in different locales, I get strange output for fr_FR in one particular host.

Here is the code,

```
#include <time.h>       /* time_t, struct tm, time, localtime, strftime */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <clocale>

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
      char buffer [32];

      setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
      cout << "LC_ALL: " << setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL) << endl;
      cout << "LC_CTYPE: " << setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL) << endl;


      time (&rawtime);
      timeinfo = localtime (&rawtime);

      strftime (buffer,sizeof(buffer),"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z",timeinfo);
      puts (buffer);

      return 0;
}
```

Before running the above program I did

```
export LANG=fr_FR.ISO8859-1
```

It gives output,

```
LC_ALL: fr_FR.ISO8859-1
LC_CTYPE: fr_FR.ISO8859-1
ven. avril 12 08:49:55 2013 UTC
```

It gives same output for both %b and %B, when I checked in another machine, it works as expected. Output,

```
LC_ALL: fr_FR.ISO8859-1
LC_CTYPE: fr_FR.ISO8859-1
jeu avr 11 23:26:24 2013 PDT
```

In one machine,

```
$date +%b
avr
$date +%B
avril
```

In problamatic machine,

```
$date +%b
avril
$date +%B
avril
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What OS is on each machine?

Comment: Both machines are RHEL5.

Answer (score 0):

The output appears correct.

"avril" is a legitimate abbreviation for "avril" [Reference](http://library.princeton.edu/departments/tsd/katmandu/reference/months.html).

"Avr" is also an abbreviation for "avril".  French months "juin" and "juillet", both beginning with the same 3 letters demonstrate that using the first 3 letters won't always work.

C++ does not specify how to abbreviate month names other than the default locale.  Thus assuming the abbreviation are short, the same length within a locale or implemented the same in various OS world wide is problematic.

Recommend checking the return value of `strftime()`.